# Modelling business attributes/amenities in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Business` model in my application, which will be storing information about

- Restaurants
- Bars
- Stores
- Hair Salons
- Etc

Some of the businesses share attributes/amenities:

- Wifi
- A/C
- Accesibility
- Etc..

But some are specific for a single type of businesses, for example restaurants:

- Take out
- Delivery
- Dress code
- Outdoor seating

I am wondering what would be the best way of modelling this information in the DB?

My current thinking:

Use a single table for `Business` that will hold all the information and attributes. Most of the attributes are boolean, therefore whenever an attribute does not apply to a business type, it will simply be `false`.

I am not sure however, if there is a better way of doing this. Also not sure about how to handle these differences at the view level. For example, when creating a business, I want the option the display/set those attributes that are applicable to the business type.

Comment: Do you expect to be querying on the type-specific fields? That'll make a big difference.

Comment: Not for now, but maybe in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way I would do it.  You should have an attribute called `business_type` that lets you choose what attributes to display.
For example in the show view:

```
<% if @business.business_type == "restaurant" %>
  Provides take out: <%= @business.take_out %>
<% end %>
```

You could use jQuery to change what fields are available on the new form based on what restaurant type it is:

```
<%= f.select :business_type, [["Restaurant", "restaurant"], ["Store", "store"]] %>
<script>
  $('#business_business_type').change(function(){
    // hide or show fields here based on this.value
  });
</script>
```

If you want to avoid having a bunch of database columns, you could use the key-value store in rails 3.2 (3/4 of the way down [this page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2?view=asciicast)):
Make a column called `amenities`. Then in `business.rb`:

```
store :amenities, accessors: [:wifi, :ac, :accessibility, ...]
```